# Subset/extract the highest values of groups in one column based on values of groups in other columns

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, highest

I'm looking at oxygen concentrations in relation to bottom trawling at different depths in inner Danish waters for the last 40 years.
I have a data frame (Oxy) with four columns: `ID`, `Date`, `Depth` and `Oxygen`. The `Oxygen` has been measured throughout many years (`Date`), at many different locations (`ID`) and at many different `Depths` down the water column, spanning from 0-50 meters.

I would like to create a data frame where I have the `Oxygen` for the last 4 meters (`Depth`) (from the bottom and 4 meters up in the water column) for each station and the corresponding date. The measurements are not by every whole meter but at varying depths. The `Depth` where the `Oxygen` has been measured are not the same for each `ID`, so for one `ID` it has been sampled at 0.2, 0.4, 0.6 meters etc. and for another `ID` it has been sampled at 0.67, 1.3, 1.55 meters etc. The `Depth` for each `ID` also varies, so for one station the deepest measurement is at 30 meters and for another one it's 46 meters.

I have about 4 million rows, so this is just an output of my data:

```
ID         Date          Depth    Oxygen
------    ----------     -----    ------
957001    2002-01-14     1.20     12.10
967503    2002-01-28     2.00     11.60
957001    2002-01-22    25.00      7.80
965206    2002-01-28     5.40     11.70
953001    2002-01-31    23.60     10.30
941101    2002-01-22     8.67     12.00
940201    2002-01-17     5.00     11.70
965404    2002-01-30    38.80      9.40
952003    2002-01-08    23.40      6.30
957101    2002-01-15     6.00     11.60
```

I have been searching on google for an answer but can't seem to find the right one. I can extract the highest value or the top 5 highest values by using `arrange(), group_by() and slice()`. However, that wouldn't work for my data frame because the measurement intervals vary in depth and it needs to be similar for all `ID's` and `Dates`.

I imagine that it could be something like; take the highest value and then keep the values that are within -4 from that highest value.

So, I need to end up with all the deepest (last 4 meters for `Depth`) measurements for `Oxygen` dependent on `ID` and `Date`.

It would look something like this:

```
ID         Date          Depth     Oxygen
------    ----------     -----     ------
957001    2002-01-14     30.20      2.10
967503    2002-01-28     28.00      1.60
957001    2002-01-22     29.00      7.80
965206    2002-01-28     30.40      5.70
953001    2002-01-31     23.60     10.30
941101    2002-01-22     28.67      7.00
940201    2002-01-17     30.00      8.70
965404    2002-01-30     38.80      9.40
952003    2002-01-08     23.40      6.30
957101    2002-01-15     46.00      1.60
```

Comment: Erik, when you said "last 4 meters from the bottom", Do we know the bottom depth at each station?. Is it registered in each station sample?

Comment: Can you confirm your example output? e.g., the greatest depth for `967503` is `2.00` in your starting data but `28.00` in the output?

Comment: @RicVillalba There are some stations that don't have samples at bottom depth, and I will sort them out. But yes, for each station sample there is an oxygen measurement registered at the bottom.

Comment: @zephryl It's was just to illustrate that I start with measurements at all depths and that I want to end with measurements at bottom depth. So it was an example of my data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as you said, filter to `Depth` greater than `max() - 4` within each `ID`. Using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

oxy %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(Depth >= max(Depth) - 4) %>%
  ungroup()
```

```
# A tibble: 9 × 4
      ID Date       Depth Oxygen
   <dbl> <date>     <dbl>  <dbl>
1 967503 2002-01-28  2      11.6
2 957001 2002-01-22 25       7.8
3 965206 2002-01-28  5.4    11.7
4 953001 2002-01-31 23.6    10.3
5 941101 2002-01-22  8.67   12  
6 940201 2002-01-17  5      11.7
7 965404 2002-01-30 38.8     9.4
8 952003 2002-01-08 23.4     6.3
9 957101 2002-01-15  6      11.6
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked out perfectly! I just added the Date to the code as well, because I need the oxygen at the last 4 meters for each station every day it was measured.
`group_by(StedID, Date)`